# What keys to choose in Notepad++ for a German keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, keyboard-layout

Notepad++'s shortcut mapper doesn't allow pressing a button to set it for an action, it has to be chosen from a list. But this list uses an English keyboard layout as a basis, so what keys should be chosen for a German keyboard?

Example: You want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> for zoom in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for zoom out (without num pad). But <kbd>+</kbd> isn't even on the list, because it's a combined key on the English keyboard layout.

(This Q&A is intended to save you time trying every option, I did that for you.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table of keys in the list and keys on the German keyboard is as follows:

```
Everthing from "Backspace" to "F12"
is the same on the German keyboard.
"Home" means "Pos1".

N++ list     German keyboard
       ~     Ö
       -     -
       =     +
       [     ß
       ]     ´
       ;     Ü
       '     Ä
       \     ^
       ,     ,
       .     .
       /     #
      <>     <>
```

This does not fit the picture for the English keyboard layout from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards) ([archive](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=British_and_American_keyboards&oldid=828603307)), but from just trying everything out, that is my list.

In the example you would choose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> for "zoom in" and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for "zoom out".